# Create multiple jQuery image pans on 1 page

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances, panning

There is a wonderful script by Manos which allows you to pan a cropped image when hovering over it. Here is the [code](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-image-panning) and here is a [demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_image_panning.html)

What I would like to do is to place multiple images on 1 page with various sizes for each image. (I tried creating a JSfiddle for this but did not work well...)

I attempted to add more than 1 on a page, but each image mirrors the action and each instance needs to be the exact same size image or it can't calculate the proper panning.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a global `$imagePan` modify the MouseMove function to accept the image in context, and instead of using id's you should be using classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/VPr52/9/

It still needs heavy optimization, calculating the widths and height each time the mouse moves, is too much, better to calculate it once and save it in the image using `$.data`.

Good luck!

Comment: UberNeet this is brilliant - different size images works as well with your update which is terrific - thank you! I'll keep testing/optimizing away and post any updates for others - thanks very much!